# jQuery Toggle Div Horizontally

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a slide out div function. Basically, it's a rectangle shaped image map - and when you click on a location on the map, a DIV slides out from the right to cover the entire map. I need to do this for multiple locations (i.e. multiple DIVs)

I tried a few functions from jQuery with no luck. The toggle effect only allows for an up or down motion, and I'm having trouble getting the .animate effect to work the way I want.

This [**Jfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rs2QK/979/) is close to what I need but Im trying to get the active DIV to slide back out before the new one slides in (and the MAP DIV should always remain static, so when a DIV slides back out, you see the map before the new div slides in).

This is whats in the Jfiddle:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('a.panel').click(function() {
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $other = $target.siblings('.active');

        if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
            $other.each(function(index, self) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                    left: $this.width()
                }, 500);
            });

            $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                left: -($target.width())
            }).animate({
                left: 0
            }, 500);
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: I found this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/vHJj7/24/

Is this the best way to set it up for multiple DIVs? I will have more than 25 DIVs...

Comment: Why you are not using jQuery toggle/slideToggle functions?

Comment: Because, to my knowledge - those functions do not allow for a horizontal movement. Only up and down or fade in/out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your jQuery snippet, I came up with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.panel').css('left', '-200px');

    $('a.panel').click(function() {
        var a = $(this);
        var p = $(a.attr('href'));
        var pw = p.width();

        //-- if we have an active panel, hide it. otherwise, just show target
        if ($('div.panel').hasClass('active')) {
            //-- reset all panels
            $('div.panel').animate({
                left: -pw
            }, 500, function() {
                //-- when that is complete, move target panel to position
                p.addClass('active').show().animate({
                    left: 0
                });
            });
        } else {
            p.addClass('active').show().animate({
                left: 0
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rs2QK/982/

- Update #1
  CSS/HTML to keep original map div (#target1) showing. The CSS is a little redundant, but given the approach, it gets the job done.
- Update #2
  Updated fiddle link. I was under the impression it updated on save. Oops.

Comment: Fantastic! This is much better than the approach I came up with Don. Its much cleaner if I'm going to add locations, as I wont have to edit the actual jQuery script. Fantastic! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don Boots, what you had was close to what I was looking for - but I think I found a better solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var visible=true;
$("#test").on('click', function() { 
    $('.t1').animate({width: visible ? 300 : 0}, "slow");
     visible=!visible;  }); 
 $("#test2").on('click', function() { 
    $('.t2').animate({width: visible ? 300 : 0}, "slow");
     visible=!visible;         
});
$("#close").on('click', function() { 
    $('.common').animate({width: visible ? 0: 0}, "slow");
     visible=!visible;         
});
```

​

[**JFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vHJj7/40/)

Comment: That is a good approach as well. I did notice that there are some inconsistencies when clicking on Map Details 1, then Map Details 2 (or vice versa).